# DataTable loading time is too slow

Tags: jquery, node.js, angular, postgresql, datatable

Well guys, i got a problem there, i was happy because i did that the table (dataTable) work in my project, but testing how much rows can be support my project, these are the times:
2000 rows: 4 seconds to show.
8000 rows: 40 seconds to show.
20000 rows: incalculated :(

I am using Angular 7, Nodejs, PostgreSQL, express, jquery for the table library.
This is my code:

The component of the registers: (list.ts) -- Here I call to dataTable and I config it --

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  users$: any[] = [];
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  public denuncias: Denuncia[];
  constructor(
    private _denunciaService: DenunciaService
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
      "paging": true,
      language: {
        processing: "Procesando...",
        search: "Buscar:",
        lengthMenu: "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
        info: "Mostrando elementos del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
        infoEmpty: "No existen registros",
        infoFiltered: "(Filtrados _MAX_ elementos en total).",
        infoPostFix: "",
        loadingRecords: "Cargando....",
        zeroRecords: "No existen registros de denuncias",
        emptyTable: "No se encontraron resultados.",
        paginate: {
          first: "Primer",
          previous: "Anterior",
          next: "Siguiente",
          last: "Último"
        },
        aria: {
          sortAscending: ": Activar para ordenar ascendentemente",
          sortDescending: ": Activar para ordenar descendentemente"
        }
      }
    };
    this.getDenuncias();
  }

  getDenuncias() {
    this._denunciaService.getDenunciasxd().subscribe(response => {
      this.denuncias = response.data;
      this.dtTrigger.next();
    },
      error => {
        console.log(<any>error);
      })
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

and this is the code HTML

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger">
        <thead class="">
            <tr>
                <th id="ID">ID</th>
                <th id="FACULTAD">Locacion</th>
                <th id="DETALLE">Detalle de los hechos</th>
                <th id="FECHA">Fecha</th>
                <th id="ESTADO">Estado</th>
                <th id="DELETE">Detalle</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="align-middle">
            <tr *ngFor="let denuncia of denuncias" class="align-middle">
                <td class="align-middle" style="font-family: consolas">
                    {{denuncia.numeroDenuncia}}
                </td>
                <td class="align-middle">
                    {{denuncia.FacultadDependencia}}
                </td>
                <td class="align-middle">
                    {{denuncia.detalleHechos}}
                </td>
                <td class="align-middle">
                    {{denuncia.fechaDenuncia}}
                </td>
                <td class="align-middle">
                    {{denuncia.Estado}}
                </td>
                <td class="align-middle">
                    <a class="button" title="Aprende a crear un blog" href="/delete/<%= data[i].numeroDenuncia %>"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is the controller in the backend:

```
const controller = {};
const { Pool } = require('pg');

var connectionString = 'postgres://me:system@localhost/antisobornodb';
const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString: connectionString,
})

controller.listar = async(request, response) => {
    try {
        const result = await pool.query(
            'SELECT "detalleHechos", "Estado","numeroDenuncia","FacultadDependencia","Estado","fechaDenuncia" ' +
            'FROM tb_anonima UNION ALL ' +
            'SELECT "detalleHechos", "Estado","numeroDenuncia","FacultadDependencia","Estado","fechaDenuncia" ' +
            'FROM tb_juridica UNION ALL ' +
            'SELECT "detalleHechos", "Estado","numeroDenuncia","FacultadDependencia","Estado","fechaDenuncia" ' +
            'from tb_natural');
        // return response.render('registros', );
        return response.status(200).send({ data: result.rows });
    } catch (err) {
        // return next(err);
        console.log(err);
    }
};
module.exports = controller;
```

This code works pretty well but just with 1-1500 rows i think, i don't need millions of rows, it's a little project for my job, maybe the maximum rows that i need to read will be 15000 or 20000,no more.

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Do not use datatable for large rows, use ag-grid etc

Comment: You should use serverside processing when you have apx. more than 4.000 rows. See https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side how you implement this in Angular (2+) DataTables I dont know. I guess you just set the options and modify your serverside script accordingly.